# Data validation issue Firebase RealTime Database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to make some security rules to allow authenticated users to access (read / write) `chats` path based on some conditions for data validation.

Here are my rules :

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "chats": {
      "$chatID": {
        ".read": "data.child('members/'+auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": "(!data.exists() && newData.child('members').exists() && newData.child('members/'+auth.uid).exists()) || data.child('members/'+auth.uid).exists()",  
      }
    },
  }
}
```

And here is my json :

```json
{
    "chats/1d771b40-917c-11ec-b57d-a55c6126c658":{
        "uid":"1d771b40-917c-11ec-b57d-a55c6126c658",
        "name":"",
        "updatedAt":1645272534466,
        "createdAt":1645272279796,
        "senderID":"user1",
        "members":{
            "user1":true,
            "user2":true
        },
        "created":true,
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it's denied for writes, can you explain me please which value has `newData` exactly ?

I have setup a very basic rule to test :

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "chats": {
      "$chatID": {
        ".read": "data.child('members/'+auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": "newData.child('members').exists()",  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That is denied, and i have also tried :

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "chats": {
      "$chatID": {
        ".read": "data.child('members/'+auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": "newData.parent().child('members').exists()",  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#existing_data_vs_new_data) i thought that `newData` was containing the json data that will happened if the write is allowed for the given path, meaning in this case :

```json
{
        "uid":"1d771b40-917c-11ec-b57d-a55c6126c658",
        "name":"",
        "updatedAt":1645272534466,
        "createdAt":1645272279796,
        "senderID":"user1",
        "members":{
            "user1":true,
            "user2":true
        },
        "created":true,
}
```

So why `newData.child('members').exists()` returns false if I understood correctly ?

I have also tested `newData.hasChild('members')` and `newData.hasChildren(['members'])` but all give the same result (False).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you testing in rules playground or trying to write from Firebase SDKs? Can you share how are you trying to update data? `newData` in this case is `"chats/1d771b40-917c-11ec-b57d-a55c6126c658"` object and `"newData.child('members').exists()"` seems to working for me.

Comment: I am using rules playground indeed that denies the request, after i took the json from my app. Thanks for specifying the value of `newData`

Comment: Can you show a screenshot the the playground with the values that you are trying to write, and the rule that is failing showing in it?

Comment: I had the issue with the path as the first json key, and the rule that was failing was :    this one  ".write": "newData.child('members').exists()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the exact JSON that should go in the specified path/locations in the update request's data.

So the location to update a chat would be: `chats/{chatId}` and data/payload as shown below:

```json
{
  "uid": "1d771b40-917c-11ec-b57d-a55c6126c658",
  "name": "",
  "updatedAt": 1645272534466,
  "createdAt": 1645272279796,
  "senderID": "user1",
  "members": {
    "user1": true,
    "user2": true
  },
  "created": true
}
```